# Gibt es ein Eigenschaftswort für den Zustand, wenn man keinen Durst hat?

Tags: single-word-request, antonym

Das Gegenteil von *hungrig* ist *satt.* Mir fällt aber kein Wort ein, das dem Zustand »ohne Durst« entspricht. In anderen Sprachen existiert ein solches Wort; zum Beispiel gibt es *dissetato* im Italienischen.

Gibt es ein derartiges Wort? Wenn nicht, was ist die eleganteste Umschreibung dafür?

Comment: Ich habe die Frage meinem fünfjährigen Sohn gestellt. Seine (scherzhaften) Antworten: *ertrunken* und *voll gesoffen* :)

Comment: tatsächlich wurde im April 1999 eine Abstimmung vom deutschen Duden herausgegeben, bei der das Wort sitt gewann. Benutzt wirde es jedoch trotzdem nicht. Quelle: Meine Erinnerung, Beleg: http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/wettbewerb-sitt-und-satt-a-45652.html

Comment: In meiner Muttersprache, im Polnischen, existieren so ein Wort ebenso wenig. Es wäre eine interessante Frage, in welchen Sprachen es existiert und wenn in nur wenigen, warum?

Comment: Verwandte Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/is-sitt-really-a-german-word

Comment: @BarthZalewski Interessanter Punkt. In der chinesischen Sprache verwendet man das Wort bǎo, was satt (oder in dem Kontext: voll) bedeutet. Chinesisch hat viele Wortkombinationen und ist sehr frei in den Kombinationsmöglichkeiten, und so kann man chī essen mit bǎo kombinieren: chībǎo, sich voll essen, satt essen. Das funktioniert allerdings nicht mit dem Wort für trinken (oder nur in Zusammenhang mit Babies und Wasser trinken gegen den Hunger). Man sagt stattdessen bù kě, nicht durstig sein.
Anm.: Leider kann man in Kommentaren keine chinesischen Zeichen platzieren.

Comment: Also, wie du siehst, meine Theorie wird auch hier bestätigt. Ich glaube, **swegi** hat die Ursache dafür  in seiner/ihrer Antwort richtig erfasst.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Es wurde mal [versucht, *sitt*  einzuführen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitt), das ist aber gescheitert, weil es einfach zu konstruiert ist.

Mit anderen Worten: Nein, gibt es nicht. Die beste Umschreibung ist dann wohl *keinen Durst haben.*

Interessanterweise fällt mir auch kein Wort im Englischen dafür ein ...

Comment: Da du es erwähnt hast, im Englischen gibt's _quenched_, vielleicht auch _(re)hydrated_.

Comment: Klingt aber auch irgendwie sehr konstruiert...

Comment: _Quenched_ klingt mir etwas veraltert, evtl. drollig, aber nicht konstruiert. Wer Durst hatte weil er Sport gemacht hat oder beim sonnigen Wetter überhitzt wurde, kann wohl sagen dass er _(re)hydrated_ geworden ist. Nach der alltäglichen Tasse Tee so was zu sagen wäre doch blöd.

Comment: Im Englischen gibt es auch keine gute Übersetzung für _satt_, soviel ich weiß.

Comment: *Quenched* klingt für mich wie eine abgebrochene Reaktion. Berufskrankheit …

Comment: [Gatorade Thirst Quencher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatorade#Products)—I don’t think it’s too constructed or that rarely used.

Comment: Ich benutze sitt schon seit Jahren. Warum auch nicht.

Comment: `quench thirst` ist IMO normales Englisch für `Durst löschen`. Quenched ist dann `durstgelöscht`

Answer (score 10):

Bei Tieren kann man sagen:

Die Pferde sind getränkt.

Das ist aber das Analogon zu gefüttert statt zu satt.

Comment: Bibeldeutsch für getränkte Menschen wäre _gelabt_.

Answer (score 9):

Ich habe mal von *sitt* gehört, aber ich glaube nicht, dass das jemand wirklich benutzt – man ist schließlich auch eigentlich nie nicht durstig.

Comment: LOL! Eine vernünftige Erklärung. :)

Comment: +1 Anmerkung zu **man ist eigentlich nie nicht durstig**.Es gibt natürlich noch den Zustand des **abgefüllt seins** (nach übermäßigen Konsum alkoholhaltiger Getränke) in dem man nicht mehr durstig ist, aber über den man besser auch nicht selber spricht.

Comment: „man ist … nie nicht durstig” – [*räusper*!](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diurese)

Comment: Hmm, ich habe vor ein paar Tagen einen halben Liter Tee am Stück getrunken, und war dann auch ziemlich voll - mehr trinken ging nicht.

Answer (score 9):

Eine erlaubte und formal korrekte Wortbildung wäre **undurstig**, also die Negation durch den Präfix »un«. Das benutzt aber niemand.
Mit drei Silben ist es auch nicht kürzer als die je nach Kontext verwendete Alternative:

- Wenn ich gefragt werde, ob ich noch etwas trinken möchte: *Nein, danke.*
- Wenn ich jemandem etwas zum Trinken mitbringen möchte: *Hast du Durst?*

Comment: Doch, *undurstig* sieht man gerade auf vielen Werbeplakaten ( http://www.horizont.net/aktuell/agenturen/pages/protected/Nicht-schoen-aber-ehrlich-Olaf-Schubert-wirbt-fuer-Sachsenquelle_106611.html ), und ich halte den Begriff für am sinnvollsten

Comment: @falkb Werbesprache ist keine Umgangssprache.

Comment: na ja, Werbe-Leute sind auch nur Menschen, die nach passenden Begriffen suchen. Und *undurstig* würde mir auch als sinnvollstes Wort einfallen. Außerdem schlägt sich Werbung, wenn sie nicht zu abwegig ist, durch die ständige Dauerbestrahlung der Menschen ziemlich gut auf die Umgangssprache nieder...

Comment: "undurstig" gibt es vielleicht ebenso wenig wie "unhungrig".
Aber jeder wüßte, was gemeint ist. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Ich verweise auf den Duden, wie sich das Baby "satt trinkt", stillen auch wir unseren Durst, bis wir gesättigt sind.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/satt

Comment: Milch ist allerdings ein (Allein)Ernährungsmittel, weswegen man davon auch satt werden kann. Von Wasser kannst man nicht satt werden ;)

Comment: Bedeutung des Wortes __"satt"__: "nicht mehr hungrig; kein Bedürfnis nach Nahrungsaufnahme mehr verspürend",  
Bedeutung des Wortes __"Nahrung"__: "Essbares, Trinkbares, das ein Lebewesen zur Ernährung, zu Aufbau und Erhaltung des Organismus braucht und zu sich nimmt"  
Beides dem Duden entnommen. :)

Comment: Auch wenn man Tee satt haben kann, bezweifle ich, dass man sich daran satt trinken kann. Bei (Mutter)Milch geht das, weil du es wirklich brauchst. Außer Milch und maximal Wasser geht da aber nichts in die Definition hinein.

Comment: Ich kann deine Argumentation nachvollziehen. Wenn du allerdings Hunger verspürst, kannst du durch die Aufnahme von Flüssigkeit ein Sättigungsgefühl erreichen. Selbiges passiert, wenn du aus "Durst" trinkst. Wobei Durst das Bedürfnis zur Aufnahme von trinkbarem (zur Ernährung) bezeichnet. Das du unter Cola kein Nahrungsmittel im herkömmlichen Sinne verstehst, ehrt dich. Ich wage allerdings zu behaupten, dass es auch möglich ist in einer Lagerhalle voll Softdrinks zu überleben. Freilich nicht mit den Zähnen. :D

Comment: @SamuelHerzog: Um das zu untermauern: Man spricht beim Baby auch davon, dass es trinkt, weil es *hungrig* ist.

Comment: Man kann sich in bestimmtem Kontext mit Wasser, oder aber auch an Wasser satt trinken:
1. Er trank Wasser, bis er keinen Hunger mehr verspürte. (z.B. hungrig ist, aber nichts zu essen hat.)
2. Er trank 2l Wasser auf einmal. Danach hatte er es satt und konnte tagelang kein Wasser sehen.

Answer (score 4):

Nein, so ein Wort gibt es nicht. Jedenfalls nicht, wenn man sich auf Wörter beschränkt, die tatsächlich im Alltag in regelmäßiger Verwendung sind.

Der Getränkehersteller Lipton hat 1999 gemeinsam mit der Dudenredaktion dazu aufgerufen, ein Adjektiv zu finden, welches das Gegenteil von »durstig« bedeutet. Rund 100.000 Teilnehmer schickten rund 45.000 verschiedene Vorschläge ein. Das Wort »**sitt**« wurde vierzigmal eingesendet und wurde von der Jury zum Sieger gekürt.

Andere Wörter, die häufig eingesendet wurden, aber aus verschiedenen Gründen ausgeschieden sind, sind:

> gecoked, liptoniced, getränkt, soff, thirstbust, cool, sattgetrunken, antidurstig, nimedu (nicht mehr durstig), börps, burps, plopp

Die Werbeindustrie hat sich hingegen (zumindest in einem Fall) für »undurstig« entschieden:
[image]

All diese Wörter haben aber eines gemeinsam: Sie werden von der Bevölkerung im Alltag nicht benutzt.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn es nicht zu ernst sein muss, kann man auch "gestillt" verwenden. Man sagt ja auch "den Durst stillen"...

Comment: "Ich bin satt und mein Durst ist gestillt." - ohne den Durst geht es nicht, aber mit ihm ist es nicht unernst.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann sagen "ich bin **durstfrei**" oder "sie ist **durstlos**".

Wenn Alkohol und dessen Gehalt eine Rolle spielen kann man **abgefüllt** sagen oder **dicht**.

Answer (score 0):

Laut dem [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS02181#XGS02181) ist das Wort *satt* nicht aufs Essen beschränkt - man kann sich auch durchaus *satt trinken*:

> zunächst von jemand, der seinen hunger oder durst gestillt hat, gewöhnlich auf ersteren bezogen
>
> ebenso sich satt trinken: saufft euch satt, weil mans gestatt.
>
> der nam mich mit sich in stadtkellr,
> liesz zapffen wein und muscatellr,
> macht meinen Jan so satt, so trund,
> das er die trepff kaum finden kunt.

Comment: Steht das nicht schon hier? https://german.stackexchange.com/a/910/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt Da steht das nur auf Babys bezogen, dass die sich *satt trinken *. Aber denen bleibt ja auch nix anderes übrig...

Answer (score -2):

Dieses Wort wird nicht gebraucht, und das erklärt auch warum irgendwelche Vorschläge nicht angenommen werden: 
wenn man satt ist, und trotzdem weiterißt, (was nur limitiert möglich ist) hat man sich überfressen.
Trinken kann man jedoch problemlos ohne Durst zu verspüren, und wenn das Fassungsvermögen erschöpft ist, geht man halt aufs Klo und weiter geht's. Man kann sich zwar mit alkoholischen Getränken besaufen, aber übertrinken geht einfach nicht. Daher braucht man auch kein Wort für einen Zustand, den es so nicht gibt. Wenn jemand nichts trinken will, hat er ja schließlich die Möglichkeit zu sagen: Danke, aber ich habe keinen Durst, oder ich bin nicht durstig.

Comment: Doch, ich hätte das Wort schon oft gebrauchen können.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhydration#Hypotone_Hyperhydratation_.28.E2.80.9EWasservergiftung.E2.80.9C.29

Comment: Du hast offensichtlich noch nie so viel in so kurzer Zeit gegessen und getrunken, dass keine Flüssigkeit mehr reingepasst hat. Übertrinken geht genau so gut wie überessen (es löst sich nur schneller wieder auf).

Comment: Der Annahme, dass es dieses Wort mangels Zustand nicht geben müsste widerspricht ja im übrigen schon die simple Tatsache, dass mehrere andere Sprachen eben sehr wohl ein exaktes Wort dafür haben.

Comment: Wenn ich Durst habe trinke ich, wenn möglich, so viel, bis ich keinen Durst mehr habe. Man kann dann natürlich aus Gefallen am Geschmack, aus Langeweile, wegen einer alkoholischen Wirkung noch weitertrinken, aber eben nicht aus Durst.  Man kann auch die Bude heizen, weil einem kalt ist, und wenn einem nicht mehr kalt ist trotzdem weiterheizen. Wie viele Liter Wasser kannst Du denn noch trinken, wenn der Durst gestillt ist, und wieso nicht 1-2 Liter mehr, oder 5 Liter oder 50 Liter?